# Поиск дубликатов по нескольким столбцам. Ошибка синтаксиса. MySQL | SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, big-data

В таблице (что ниже) пытаюсь 3-мя способами реализовать поиск **дубликатов по нескольким атрибутам**. Ни один не срабатывает. Предположение вот в чем, после оператора `WHERE` стоит что-то не то (простейшие комбинации перебора уже исчерпаны).

[image: Таблица]

1. Машина просто замолкает, даже через полчаса - ничего.

```
SELECT * FROM sales
WHERE region IN (SELECT region FROM sales GROUP BY region HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

AND totalrevenue IN (SELECT totalrevenue FROM sales GROUP BY totalrevenue  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) 

AND TotalCost IN (SELECT TotalCost FROM sales GROUP BY TotalCost HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

AND TotalProfit IN (SELECT TotalProfit FROM sales GROUP BY TotalProfit HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) 

ORDER BY country
```

2. Способ менее похожий на решение, но выдает синтаксическую ошибку:

```
SELECT * FROM sales 

WHERE **>>>че-т неправильно здесь<<<** TotalRevenue, TotalCost, TotalProfit, COUNT(totalrevenue) as cnt

GROUP BY TotalRevenue, TotalCost, TotalProfit

HAVING COUNT(cnt > 1)
```

Comment: Как понимать `WHERE TotalRevenue, TotalCost, TotalProfit`???

Comment: @ArchDemon там надо как в первом варианте? Отдельно прописать для каждого атрибута?

Comment: Вы русскими словами напиши что вы ждёте от представленной выше строчки.

Comment: @ArchDemon, я жду, что where как оператор if сработает, ну не в смысле прям так, но для краткости

Comment: Вы ответите на мой вопрос или будете писать ненужные вещи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать оконные функции:

```
    WITH a AS(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER(PARTITION BY TotalR, TotalC, 
    TotalP) AS dubl
    From t2
    )
    SELECT * FROM a WHERE dub>1
```

Comment: Нужно поправить: для функции ROW_NUMBER необходимо определить порядок сортировки(ORDER BY)

Comment: Это не необходимо, запрос работает и без ORDER BY. Вопрос удобства.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал. Видимо особенность MySql, т.к. в T-SQL для нумерации нужно явно задать порядок сортировки.

Comment: Спасибо! Бомба, на курсе не рассказывали про оконные функции

Comment: Рада, что помогла . Изучите на досуге оконные функции - они дают много интересных возможностей. И удачи!